# how can i ensure that multiple images are deleted if the user clicks on save

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I believe this can be done with jquery. I have an edit preview which allows a user to delete the images. each image has a x button which directs to the the **destroyImg** function if clicked. The issue here is that the delete happens even before the user clicks the save button. The goal is to allow only a number of images intended to be deleted must be destroyed if the user clicks save.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSEnm.png)

### blade file

```
@for($i=0;  $i< count($image = $post->images()->get()); $i++)
    @if($i==0)
        <div class=" ">
            <div class="editImages ">
                <div class = "img-order" > 
                    <img class="posts-img crop" src="/images/{{$image[$i]['image']}}" alt="first slide">   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
             
    @else
        <div class="">
            <div class="editImages">
                <div class = "img-order" > <img class="posts-img crop" src="/images/{{$image[$i]['image']}}" alt="first slide">   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form action="/trash/img-edit/{{$image[$i]->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      
        @csrf
        @method ('DELETE')
                 
        <div class="">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="">
                    <button>&times; </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
@endfor

<form action="/p/update/{{ $post->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    @csrf
    @method ('PATCH')

           <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' post image') }}</label>
                <input type="file", class="form-control-file" id ="image" multiple = "multiple" name="image[]">
    @error('image')
           <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
               <strong>{{ $message }}</strong> 
          </div>       
    @enderror

          <label for="about" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' write something here') }}</label>
               <input id="about" type="text" class="form-control 
  @error('about') is-invalid @enderror" name="about"  value="{{ old('about') ?? $post->about }}" required autocomplete="about" autofocus>

  @error('about')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
          
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        <button> save </button>     
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

### postcontroller

```
public function destroyImg(images $images, $id)
{
    $try = images::find($id); 
    $try->delete();
   
    if (Auth::guard('web')->check()){
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->id() ;
        return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
    }
    if (Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->check()){
        $admin = Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->id() ;
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard',['admin'=>$admin]);
    }
}

public function update(Post $post, Request $request)
{
    
    $data = request()->validate(['about' => 'required',]);
    $post->update( $data);
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $files = $request->file('image');
        foreach($files as $file) {
             
            $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $name = str_replace('','-',$name);
            echo $name;
                
            $file->move('images',$name);
                
            $post->images()->create(['image' => $name ]);
        }
    }

    if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
        $user = Auth::guard('web')->id() ;
        return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
    }

    if (Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->check()) {
        $admin = Auth::guard('SuperAdmin')->id() ;
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard',['admin'=>$admin]);
    }
}
```

### routes

```
Route::delete('/trash/img-edit/{oneimage}', 'PostController@editDestroyImg')->name('edit.delete');
Route::patch('/p/update/{post}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

Comment: General point: You don't need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form` if the form won't be uploading any files. I'm thinking of your Delete form in particular.

Comment: "The issue here is that the delete happens even before the user clicks the save button"...that's because clicking the X button in the delete form submits the delete form directly. It's a separate form. That's what buttons do (if you don't change their behaviour). If you don't want this to happen individually, and want no instructions to be sent to the server until Save is clicked, then you need to have a single edit form - this would need to map to a model which includes a mechanism for managing the images. Currently you have two (or more, if there are >1 images) completely independent forms

Comment: @ADyson one form hits the update while the other hits the destroyImg thats why using one form is a challenge

Comment: i would need to track a group of  images that have been selected to be deleted and then delete them  at once if the save button is clicked

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: "i would need to track a group of images that have been selected to be deleted and then delete them at once if the save button is clicked"...yes, that's correct. It's a reasonably common thing to do. Basically your edit form would submit a list of IDs of images to be deleted, based on what the user selected (just some simple checkboxes would do the job). Then the server-side code would take that list and, in addition to updating the main record, carry out any deletions which have been selected.

Comment: @ADyson  ok i think i am heading there let me give it a go.